# Convert from rxjava retrolambda expression to classic

Tags: android, rx-android, retrolambda

I use retrolambda expression

```
 _rxBus = getRxBusSingleton();
    _disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

    ConnectableFlowable<Object> tapEventEmitter = _rxBus.asFlowable().publish();

    _disposables
            .add(tapEventEmitter.subscribe(event -> {

             if (event instanceof EmployeeMvvmActivity.TapEvent) {
                _showTapText();
            }

            }));
```

Everything work fine. Because of Roboelectric testing i need to convert retrolambda expression to classic. I have tried

```
_disposables.add(tapEventEmitter.subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object event) {
            if (event instanceof EmployeeMvvmActivity.TapEvent) {
                _showTapText();
            }
        }
    }));
```

I have got error cannot resolve method 'subscribe(anonymous rx.functions.Action1(java.lang.object)'.

Comment: It's not clear why you can't use retrolambda on your tests too.

Comment: By use retrolambda Execution test build failed. An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_101).

Comment: Retrolambda should work for your tests too, you could try fixing that before moving your code to java7 anonymous classes.

Comment: I haven't used retrolambda, but want to ask whether you selected a right class (Action1<Object>).

Comment: I want to ask how can I lambda expression convert to classic expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Action1` comes from Rx1 while you're using Rx2. Instead you have to use the `Consumer` interface.

```
_disposables.add(tapEventEmitter.subscribe(new Consumer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Object event) {
        if (event instanceof EmployeeMvvmActivity.TapEvent) {
            _showTapText();
        }
    }
}));
```